# JPlayer - Media Error in IE

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, mime-types, jplayer

im having a wierd error when i try to access to my JPlayer 2.2.0 @ IE.

Using Chrome and FF i have no issues but when i try to run @ IE10/IEtester i get this error:

**"Media URL could not be loaded. Check if media URL is valid."**

I found here some threads with similar problems but i cant figure why this is not working.

My Player: http://www.fbnet.org/barra/barra.php

My .htaccess:

```
AddType audio/mpeg mp3
AddType audio/mp4 m4a
AddType audio/ogg ogg
AddType audio/ogg oga
AddType audio/webm webma
AddType audio/wav wav
```

my server allow .htaccess changes so its fine.

Then i tested this thing @ my JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function (event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3:"http://62.75.159.237:8888/;stream/1"
            }).jPlayer("play");
        },
        swfPath: "http://www.fbnet.org/jp/js/",
        supplied: "mp3",
        solution: "html,flash",
        errorAlerts:true,
        wmode: "window"
    });         
});
```

Switched **solution: "html,flash"** to **"flash,html"** and player works @ IE.

The thing is: i want to have HTML as 1st option.

what am i missing here? Any ideas ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is for video, but i had an issue like that, so if u can see if the Inspector in IE is finding a file, then add ../ to it..
maybe make a .fla file to IE and add ../ in the code, like my ex. for the flv.

Hope its OK that i just add a little info, bc. i have the same problem in IE, but found a fix seaching the web.

Can see thats there is alot that have problemt with IE and the "Media URL could not be loaded" after seaching, i found out that if I use FLV fil for IE and did a ../ to the path, then it will work for IE.

So i started with this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
                ready: function () {
                    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                        mp4: "video/Soccer.mp4",
                        webmv: "video/Soccer.webm",
                        flv: "video/Soccer.flv",
                        m4v: "video/Soccer.m4v",
                        ogv: "video/Soccer.ogv",
                        poster: "video/Soccer.png"
                    });
                },
                //error: function (event) {
                   // console.log(event.jPlayer.error);
                   // console.log(event.jPlayer.error.type);
                //},
                swfPath: "add/jplayer.swf",
                errorAlerts: true,
                supplied: "mp4, webmv, flv, m4v, ogv",
                solution: "html,flash",
                size: {
                    width: "640px",
                    height: "360px",
                    cssClass: "jp-video-360p"
                },
                smoothPlayBar: true,
                keyEnabled: true
            });


            $("#jplayer_inspector").jPlayerInspector({ jPlayer: $("#jquery_jplayer_1") });
        });
        //]]>
</script>
```

And that was not working i IE, but in FF and Safari, iPhone/iPad. 
And ended up with this, thats works 100% in FF, Safari, IE and iPhone/iPad...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ready: function () {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {        
                    mp4: "video/Soccer.mp4",
                    webmv: "video/Soccer.webm",  //WEBM. works for FF
                    flv: "../video/Soccer.flv",  //FLV. works for IE, but u need ../ in front of the path...
                    m4v: "video/Soccer.m4v",  //M4V. works for FF, Saf, iPhone/iPad
                    ogv: "video/Soccer.ogv",                   
                    poster: "video/Soccer.png"
                });
            },
            //error: function (event) {
               // console.log(event.jPlayer.error);
               // console.log(event.jPlayer.error.type);
            //},
            swfPath: "add/jplayer.swf",
            errorAlerts: true,
            supplied: "mp4, webmv, flv, m4v, ogv",
            solution: "html,flash",
            size: {
                width: "640px",
                height: "360px",
                cssClass: "jp-video-360p"
            },
            smoothPlayBar: true,
            keyEnabled: true
        });


        $("#jplayer_inspector").jPlayerInspector({ jPlayer: $("#jquery_jplayer_1") });
    });
    //]]>
```